# Is there any way to getpeername() in Python after the socket disconnects?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a simple server like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('localhost', 50000))
server.listen(5)

# Set TCP Keepalive
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)
server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 3)
server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 5)

connection, client_address = server.accept()

while True:
    try:
        data = connection.recv(1024)
    except socket.error:
        print "%s dropped out" % (connection.getpeername(),)
        break

    if data:
        print "%s: %s" % (connection.getpeername(), data)
    else:
        print "%s disconnected" % (connection.getpeername(),)
        break
```

I use TCP Keepalive to figure out if a client disappears (rather than properly disconnects).

The problem I'm seeing is that when a client does disappear, and I catch the socket.error exception, my print statement tries to figure out which client disconnected by using connection.getpeername(), which no longer works. It throws a

```
socket.error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

exception.

In this simple example, there's only one client that can connect at any one time, but with more complex code that handles multiple clients at once, it might be useful to know which client dropped out.

Once a socket has disconnected, is there no way to know what endpoint it was previously connected to?
Why does the `connection` object not retain the client's IP/port information in `connection.getpeername()`,
even after the client disconnects? Is this because the `connection` object is potentially reusable?

How can I make my code actually work, and print out which client dropped out? Do I need to store the output of `connection.getpeername()` in a variable, so I can recall it later? This would mean if I have multiple
clients, I would need to store the `connection.getpeername()` value for every client in a list?

I know that using `socket` is fairly low level, and I'm pretty sure using `SocketServer.TCPServer` would be easier in the real word - I'm just trying to understand the low-level networking involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a limitation of the OS interface. A binary (C) program would also be unable to get the peer name after the socket is known to be disconnected. It's kind of an unfortunate wart. You *can't* re-use the socket for a new connection so there's no good reason I can think of why the peer name couldn't be retrieved, but... it can't.

First idea is to use a separate `dict` with the socket object serving as key through which you'd look up the associated client address:

```
saved_addr = {}
...
connection, client_address = server.accept()
saved_addr[connection] = client_address`
while True:
    try:
        data = connection.recv(1024)
    except socket.error:
        print("{} disconnected".format(saved_addr[connection]))
```

Second would be to create a separate class to wrap the socket. The class can save the peer address you get from `accept` and give it back to you when needed. In the meantime, it can transparently delegate all other operations to the underlying socket.

Demonstration:

```
import socket
import time

class ConnectedSocket:
    def __init__(self, sock, peer):
        self.sock = sock
        self.peer = peer
    def get_peer(self):
        return self.peer
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.sock, name)

def run_server(port):
    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind(('', port))
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        csock, addr = server.accept()
        csock = ConnectedSocket(csock, addr)
        print("Accepted from {}".format(addr))

        while True:
            time.sleep(.5)
            try:
                csock.send(b'Hello')
            except socket.error as err:
                print("Error {} sending to peer {}".format(err, csock.get_peer()))
                csock.close()
                break

run_server(9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use ti check if a socket is closed before getting the sock address:

```
    try:
        hostname: str = SOCKNAME.socket.getpeername()[0]
    except (socket.error):
        # socket is closed
        return
```